# Issue with images which have no sizes available

Tags: uploads, media-library, images

I noticed that, in older images uploads of mine, the sizes aren't properly available. The original files shows up but there aren't sizes linked to the image, and full size displays : "Full Size (0 x 0)". As I said, this is only happening with images I uploaded before, all the recent ones are fine. Here is a screenshot, it might help.

[image: No sizes available :(]

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Comment: What about the image URL, does it work? The snapshot you posted, does the image **and thumbs** reside in the upload folder?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's a Database Issue. If it were the actual image it wouldn't show up. I've had the same issue before but with only a few images luckily. I believe it was caused by a database error. I was having issues on the shared server at the time, and imported quite a bit of content from another site I use for testing. If you have a back-up of the Database you can try restoring the DB to fix the issues. I ended up re-loading the images since I had so few.

Comment: It's probably a DB issue, this I agree. I have back-up but I suspect the problem to be quite old, and I would lost too many changes... and uploading the images again would take a lonnnnnnnng time (2000+ photos). Ha, that's difficult, I was hoping that a plugin could fix this issue somehow.

Comment: @TigrouMeow : if you choose one problematic image, "whatever.jpg", and search for its occurrences in the database, what do you find?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happening when the image had some format not web compliant. Eg.: CMYK.

The solution is to "save for web" in any image editor and re-upload.

Comment: Those images didn't have this issue in the past actually :(

Comment: I've remember hearing about CMYK images causing issues before, but I've never experienced it. Since these images were working correctly at one time, points to another issue. If the images or the cropped by WordPress versions are still on the file server I'd suspect a DB issue maybe caused by a plug-in or a number of other possibilities.